# How to assign keyboard shortcut for moving to next virtual desktop in kde plasma 5?

Tags: kubuntu, workspaces, kde5

In desktop environments like Unity, Cinnamon, MATE, the combination <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>←</kbd>/<kbd>→</kbd> changes the workspace.

How to assign custom keyboard shortcuts in kde plasma 5 to change workspaces (i.e. virtual desktops)?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Kubuntu 18.04 and Kubuntu 19.04 use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd>, <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd>, and so on to change to the relevant desktop:

[image: System Settings window showing shortcuts to change virtual desktops]

If you want to move to the desktop to the left or the right, assign appropriate shortcuts for those actions. If the keyboard shortcuts you input conflict with existing ones, the system will let you know.